# Vue.js passing data using props to vue-full-calendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar

I am building a webpage that consists on multiple calendars. In my MySQL database i have a table that contains the projects, and each project is linked with another table that contains the answers per project on a specific date.
The page loads a calendar per project, and i have to  highlight on the calendar the dates that have answers in the database.

The code is as follows : 
Here i get all the projects, and send the dates to the props, so i can later fill in main the events with the dates.

```
      <template>


    <div v-bind="getAllProjects" class="tile is-vertical is-8" @click="clickedDiv" >
      <div class="tile"  >
        <div  v-for="val in allProjects" :key="val.projectName"     class="tile is-parent is-8" >

          <my-message  v-bind:title=val.projectName  v-bind:dates= val.answeredDates body=""></my-message>

        </div>


  </div>
    </div>


    </template>

    <code>


    import axios from "axios";

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          allProjectsURI:
            "http://localhost:8081/agilebot/webapi/projects/allprojects",
          allProjects: [],
          dates: []
        };
      },
      computed: {},
      methods: {
        getAllProjects: function() {
          var self = this;
          axios
            .get(this.allProjectsURI)
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data);
              this.allProjects = response.data;
              this.dates = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        },

        clickedDiv: function(event) {
          console.log(event.target);
        }
      },

      beforeMount() {
        this.getAllProjects();
      }
    };

</code
```

The format i get all the projects and datesfrom my database is:

```
 [
    {
        "answeredDates": [
            "2018-08-17",
            "2018-08-22",
            "2018-08-24",
            "2018-08-25"
        ],
        "channel": "testbot",
        "projectId": 1,
        "projectName": "test"
    },
    {
        "answeredDates": [
            "2018-08-22"
        ],
        "channel": "testbot",
        "projectId": 2,
        "projectName": "test2"
    },
    {
        "answeredDates": [],
        "channel": "testbot",
        "projectId": 3,
        "projectName": "test3"
    }
]
```

And i want to send this format to main.js , where i have imported vue-full-caldendar and  initialized my vue component:

Here is the main.js

```
  import FullCalendar from "vue-full-calendar";
    Vue.use(FullCalendar);

    Vue.component('my-message', {
  props: ['dates'],
  data: function(){
    var customEvents = [];
    dates.forEach((event) => {
      customEvents.push({
       title: 'schedule',
      // start: event.start

      start: event
      })
    })
            return {
              isVisible: true,
              events: customEvents,
              config: {
                defaultView: 'month',
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                  console.log(event)
                },
                eventClick: (event) => {

                  this.selected = event;
                  console.log(event);
                  //router.push("myreports")
                },


                dayClick (date, event, view) {
                 // console.log(date, event, view)
                  console.log(date.format())
                  console.log(event);
                }


              },
              selected: {},

              methods: {
                refreshEvents() {
                  this.$refs.calendar.$emit('refetch-events')
                },
                eventSelected(event) {
                  this.selected = event;
                  console.log(event);
                },


              }
            }
          }
```

The problem is that vue shows an error of not recognizing the date array "ReferenceError: dates is not defined at VueComponent.data (main.js?1c90:58)" , in which i store all the dates, so i can pass them to main via props and then use them to fill the events in order to highlight the dates on each calendar.

Comment: When you do `dates.forEach((event) => {` what does `event` look like? Is it like `{
        "answeredDates": [
            "2018-08-17",
            "2018-08-22",
            "2018-08-24",
            "2018-08-25"
        ],
        "channel": "testbot",
        "projectId": 1,
        "projectName": "test"
    }` as you showed? If not, then please show the correct info. If it is like you showed, then you can't simply assign this whole thing as the start date. You have to pick a date from the properties within it. It's not clear how you would be choosing which one to use.

Comment: yes, i agree, but the main problem is this error: ReferenceError: dates is not defined
    at VueComponent.data (main.js?1c90:58 
It does not recognize the array which i pass to props

Comment: Ah ok. You didn't mention the exact error before. I suggest you edit that into the question so it's more precise. Unfortunately I'm not a vue expert (I just know fullCalendar), and I can't really see why that's happening, but presumably it's not scoped properly. Perhaps someone with experience of vue will be able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: `dates` isn't lexically scoped, it's on the instance, so `this.dates.forEach`

Comment: i tried that too, i get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: @EraldoForgoli then whatever you are passing in the `dates` prop is not defined. Because `data()` can definitely access props this way, as shown here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEzNvo

Comment: The point is that i want to iterate through the dates, so i can create events for each date (each event highlights the date in the FullCalendar, which is the puropse of the code)